# What method does SciKit-Learn use to do basic LinearRegression?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

What is the embedded method? I tried looking inside the lib but I cannot find one.
If it is gradient descent, what is the specific one? SGD?ADAM?ADAGRAD?Momentum? Etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()`:

> From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary
>   Least Squares ([scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L1047-L1264)) wrapped as a predictor object.

You can see the source code for the implementation in [`scikit-learn/sklearn/linear_model/base.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py)